# XGBoost input data dimension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xgboost, data-fitting

I am working on time series. I have collected data having 10 different channels and put them in a pandas.DataFrame. I have a pandas.DataFrame of 10 columns (per channel) and 10 rows (per value). I have only one label for this data frame. It is a binary number.

Ex.: For a data frame of 10 columns and 10 rows, the label that I have is "0".

The problem is that I cannot use .fit in XGBoost having these inputs. I am having this error: "IndexError: tuple index out of range".

So far I have tried putting the binary label in a list, although it is non-sense. I also thought about using interpolation on this binary label so that it has the same dimension as my input, which is also non-sense because this label is representing the ensemble of my training data, not one row / column of the data.

I would like to be able to use .fit() on my model using the parameters having correct dimension. Any thoughts how I can resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Either those (10,10) values are a single datapoints - in which case it should be a single row with 100 columns -  or they represent 10 datapoints - for which there will be 10 labels (can all be 0 of course). Which one is it?

Comment: Hello @VaM, thank you for your answer. In fact, you can imagine that I have a Bluetooth device that is measuring multiple channel (A, B, C...) So the column in my data frame corresponds to different channels. Each channel is measuring a series of data, thus I have 10 row per channel. To answer your question, I don't think I can call these "single datapoints". I rather say it's the second option.

Comment: @VaM in fact, I had a dictionary at the beginning. But I wanted to put them in a data frame thinking that it would be easier. It turns out, it is not easier. :)